# 'syntaxError: Unexpected end of input' while coding a discord bot in javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, discord

I'm working on a bot that detects words like 'communism' and 'socialism' in my discord server (it's an inside joke) but I keep encountering a error saying 'syntaxError: Unexpected end of input'. If anyone could tell me why I am experiencing this error, and how to fix it, it would be greatly appreciated.
Here is my code so far:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'communism') {
    msg.reply('ISM SPOTTED')
  } else if(msg.content === 'socialism') {
    msg.reply('ISM SPOTTED')
  } else if(msg.content === 'capitalism') {
    msg.reply('ISM SPOTTED')
  } else if(msg.content === 'sexism') {
    msg.reply('ISM SPOTTED')
  } else if(msg.content === 'racism') {
    msg.reply('ISM SPOTTED')
  } else if(msg.content === 'fascism') {
    msg.reply('ISM SPOTTED')
  } else if(msg.content === 'naxism') {
    msg.reply('ISM SPOTTED')
  } else if(msg.content === 'marxism') {
    msg.reply('ISM SPOTTED')
};

client.login('[my token]');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
  } else if(msg.content === 'marxism') {
    msg.reply('ISM SPOTTED')
};
```

to this:

```
  } else if(msg.content === 'marxism') {
    msg.reply('ISM SPOTTED')
  }
});
```

You are missing a closing parenthesis and curly brace.